# Find div and then go backward to a specific div (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the matching "identifier" and then add a class to the div with classname "two", for example "found".

html example

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="box">
    
    /* Part ONE */
    <div class="one">
      <div class="one_one">
        <span class="identifier">1234</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    /* Part TWO */
    <div class="two"></div>

  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I tried:

```
var identifier = $("#list").find(".box > .one > .one_one > span:contains('1234')");

if (....) {
    identifier.closest(".one").addClass("found");
}
```

I only managed to go back to the div with the classname "one", but I need the div with classname "two" (unfortunately it is outside the parent tree of the identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the DOM up to a common parent and then find the target element within that parent.  For example:

```
identifier.closest(".box").find(".two").addClass("found");
```